# Future sql timestamp?

Tags: java, sql

Is it possible with sql syntax to make a value in a TimeStamp column 60 minutes ahead of the current time? Or do you have to get the current time, make it into a String, add 60 minutes (1 hour) to the time value, then insert that?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What version of Sql, and are you referring to the `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` data type?

Comment: @Kirk Timestamp data type

Comment: why not use DATEADD(MINUTE,60,GETDATE()) instead of timestamp?

Comment: @ItalianStallion the program I'm creating needs to store different dates depending on the situation; it won't always be 60 minutes (it could be anywhere from 10 minutes to 7 days, depending)

Comment: @ItalianStallion, not all RDBMSs have a dateadd function.  Hence the first two comments.

Comment: It might behoove you to do your logic in java and send the correct datetime value as a query parameter.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm working on that now, I was just making sure there wasn't a much easier way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function in MySQL to do this.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Note that [`SYSDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate):

> Returns the current date and time as a value in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Comment: That's selecting though. I want to do this on insert

Comment: @user2781959 `DATE_ADD(...)` just returns an expression; you can put it wherever you want; e.g. you could `INSERT INTO my_table (date_column) VALUES (DATE_ADD(...));`.

Comment: Awesome, but one more question.  In my program the time is stored in one value which is in minutes.  Because of this, is it possible to make the "Interval" field something like "INTERVAL 1440 MINUTES", or can it only be "valid" (1-59 minutes, 1-23 hours, etc.)

Comment: @user2781959 I expect that `INTERVAL 1440 MINUTES` would work, but the correct answer to that question is "try it and see!" Also make sure you *read the documentation* I linked, because if you provide a non-integer interval, the result may not be what you initially expect.

Answer (score 1):

Transact-SQL: `SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` Where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be a time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset then resolves to a DateTime.

MYSQL: `SELECT DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);`

If you're using PostgreSQL and want to replicate this function, it would be advisable to create this type of function using the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dateadd(character varying, integer, date) 
RETURNS date AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
p_Interval ALIAS FOR $1;
p_N ALIAS FOR $2;
p_Date ALIAS FOR $3;

BEGIN
if p_Interval = 'm' then
return p_Date + cast(p_N || ' months' as interval);
elseif p_Interval = 'y' then
return p_Date + cast(p_N || ' years' as interval);
elseif p_Interval = 's' then
return p_Date + cast(p_N || ' seconds' as interval);
elseif p_Interval = 'min' then
return p_Date + cast(p_N || ' minutes' as interval);
else
raise exception 'dateadd interval parameter not supported';
return null;
end if;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I want to be able to do more than one hour; depending on the situation, it might be anywhere from 10 minutes to 1 week.  This makes a new column which only supports one hour ahead of the current time.

Comment: [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html) This page offers the full gambit of datetime functionality offered in PostgreSQL (including intervals available for use), which can be easily added to this function. And the function does not create a new column, just returns a date.

Comment: In addition, if you're looking to add the time on insert you could declare a variable, set it's value based on a DateAdd() function then insert it into your database.

Comment: so I would create a Date variable to do this?

Comment: Yes, you would. You would do something like `InsertDate = tablename.columnname%TYPE;` Then you'd set the variable using the function. Please keep in mind, this is for PostgreSQL so some of the syntax will be different in other databases. But the concept should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it is MS sql server this should work

```
select getdate()                -- current datetime
select dateadd(mi,60,getdate()) -- current datetime + 60 seconds
```